# Formulário esperando uma requisição

Tags: java, c#, banco-de-dados

**Problema**

---

Meu formulário faz uma determina `requisição` a um banco de dados (seleciona, inserir, atualizar, deletar valores), porém sempre que essas requisições são feitas um travamento ocorrer no formulário (um congelamento)! Como evitar que os formulários recebem esses travamentos independe de requisição?

---

**Observação:** Quanto maior for a requisição mais demorado é o travamento. Um exemplo é um `select * from tabela;` que capturar uma grande quantidade de valores no banco de dados. Já tive ambos os problemas em JAVA e C#.

> **Atenção:** quando digo requisição estou me referindo a conexão e busca no banco de dados.

Comment: Você está falando de requisição ajax feita com JavaScript? Neste caso, você deveria usar uma requisição assíncrona em vez de síncrona.

Comment: Como esta fazendo essas requisições, por ajax? Por acaso esta usando `async: false`? Se estiver tem que mudar isso.

Comment: Estou com o @bfavaretto nessa, em relação ao que entendi da sua questão.

Comment: @bfavaretto bom não utilizo linguagens web nesses projetos, são formulário (Janelas) desktop. A janela que acaba congelando até que a requisição ao banco termine.

Comment: Ah, agora está claro. Então veja a resposta do Danimar Ribeiro, acho que é o que você está buscando.

Comment: `select * from tabela` a cada requisição? Algo está **muito** errado aí.

Comment: Um formulário tem a função de gerar um relatório! Ao clicar no botão o relatório é gerado com valores do banco de dados. Devo dizer que uma requisição foi feita ao banco de dados? @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior há várias otimizações a fazer: não usar `select *`é apenas uma delas. Você pode implementar paginação, cache... Já seriam excelentes começos para deixar sua pesquisa mais performática. No lado do BD, criar os índices pertinentes, etc

Comment: Entendi, obrigado @TiagoCésarOliveira vou pesquisar sobre o assunto. Passei o exemplo do `select * from tabela` como uma forma simples que todos entendam.

Answer (score 5):

Se seu problema é consultar uma grande quantidade de dados, não importa a linguagem, uma consulta direta sempre vai travar (lock no processo) enquanto espera o retorno do banco de dados.

A melhor alternativa é realizar uma consulta assíncrona, isto é, o processo (thread) que faz a consulta não precisa ficar bloqueada esperando a resposta do banco de dados, neste caso, existira um método de callback para receber a resposta do banco quando ela terminar de ser consultada.

Segue um link explicando como realizar esse tipo de consulta da **maneira mais simples** em C#:

- http://www.macoratti.net/12/03/c_oasql.htm

Na versão 5.0 do C# foram incluidas as palavras magicas **async** e **await** que resolvem o callback. Segue um link explicando essa utilização:

- http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 2):

Alguns pontos poderiam ser levados em consideração para uma otimização:

- Sua tabela tem índices corretamente criados? Caso você faça uma consulta utilizando LIKE e a tabela for grande, sem índice, a performance será prejudicada.
- Está buscando por ID? Na hora de um delete ou um update, a chave é o ID da tabela? Isso também pode influenciar.
- Na hora de buscar dados não faça select * from, mas descrimine cada atributo select campoA, campoB from.
- Se a tabela tem muitos dados o correto é fazer uma consulta pagina. Busque pouco a pouco as informações.
- No caso de um CRUD não é muito aconselhado paginação pois o usuário espera uma resposta imediata a sua ação. O usuário geralmente quer um feedback imediato para uma ação de CRUD - normalmente algo bem simples.

Se sua tabela estiver muito grande (milhões de registros) você poderia utilizar técnicas para diminuir o tamanho da tabela:

- Partir a tabela (PessoasNomeABC, PessoasNomeDEF,...)
- Partição por recursos do próprio banco de dados (diversos bancos já tem essa funcionalidade)
- Reduzir a quantidade de colunas indexadas

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente você deve usar threads, ou usar métodos assíncronos no .net 4.5.

Da uma lida melhor a respeito de threads, e o async.

http://www.buildando.com.br/2013/12/programacao-assincrona-com-async-e.html